# how to tell helm switch-to-buffer to make new buffer option last?

Tags: helm

When I switch buffers using helm, the first option is prefixed with `[?]` and tries to create a buffer named exactly what I typed. I find that this is the right behavior for creating files, but it is annoying for switching buffers. I'd prefer the first choice be one of the existing buffers. Can I make the `[?]` appear as the last option in the list instead?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use [helm-mini](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-7) or `helm-buffers-list` (similar to `helm-mini` but use `ido-virtual-buffers`. Don't use stock `switch-to-buffer` in helm-mode. Here is [a demo](http://tuhdo.github.io/static/part3/helm-mini.gif).

Comment: `helm-buffers-list` was exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by **Tu Do**, `helm-buffers-list` places the option to create a new buffer as the last choice. So it's just a matter of using it instead of `switch-to-buffer`.